Error Mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
The problem started when the computer powered off.
I got that error message: Error Mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/aly/Home: Unknown error when mounting /dev/sda2

aly@aly-OptiPlex-780:/var/www/SocialSphere$ lsblk -f this comment output:
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/4ktube/75
loop1
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/4ktube/82
loop2
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop3
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/264
loop4
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/278
loop5
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/code/156
loop6
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/code/157
loop7
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core20/2182
loop8
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core20/2264
loop9
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core18/2812
loop10
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/core22/1122
loop11
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/firefox/4090
loop12
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/firefox/4136
loop13
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/172
loop14
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gnome-42-2204/176
loop15
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop16
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/pyqt5-runtime-core20/9
loop17
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snap-store/959
loop18
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd/21184
loop19
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/157
loop20
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd/21465
loop21
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
loop22
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/telegram-desktop/5791
loop23
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/telegram-desktop/5820
loop24
     squash 4.0                                                    0   100% /snap/vlc/3777
loop25
                                                                   0   100% /snap/core18/2823
sda                                                                         
├─sda1
│                                                                           
├─sda2
│    ntfs         Home  24742E82742E56B8                                    
├─sda3
│    ntfs         System Reserved
│                       9A668A94668A70B5                                    
├─sda4
│    ntfs               282492AC24927C8E                                    
├─sda5
│    vfat   FAT32       9D79-D2B0                                           
├─sda6
│    vfat   FAT32       E53C-E036                             504.9M     1% /boot/efi
└─sda7
     ext4   1.0         e27ed1a0-7e15-4cbf-b542-cb09b7dae50b    6.3G    81% /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
                                                                            /
sr0


What is sda2. And is it already mounted as /home? Post this in question above: lsblk -f

I have to execute lsblk -f and add its output to the question

Since NTFS, is Windows fast startup on. Windows may turn it back on with updates, so even if you turned it off before, it may be back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

I solved the problem by reinstall Ubuntu
